# What is the maximum size of Scripting.Dictionary?

Tags: excel, vba, scripting, vbscript

I am trying to find what is the upper limit of Scripting.Dictionary? Is there one?

It could be either limit on number of elements or size of memory. I could not trace any info on that.

Comment: Well, some say [If you have to ask, you're probably doing something wrong](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/03/01/1775759.aspx). Why do you need this info and what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I have been reviewing the code for Dictionary sorting and the implementation was limited to 32,767 elements in the dictionary. And that triggered my question. I am afraid I do not try to achieve anything spectacular apart from feeding my curiosity :)

Comment: The last test I did only went up to a million, which Dictionary handled fine (although Collection was more efficient than Dictionary above 500K rows) http://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2012/07/10/comparing-two-lists-vba-udf-shootout-between-linear-search-binary-search-collection-and-dictionary/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From everything I've ever encountered (and can't seem to find any documentation to contradict this), the dictionary has no implicit upper limit and is only limited by the amount of memory you have available.

Comment: One would think but at least data type of Count would put a constrain, but MSDN is very vague in this subject: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5t9h9579(v=vs.84).aspx

Comment: It's not too hard to figure it out: `? typename(createobject("scripting.dictionary").count)` gives `Long`